# How to upload two types of files into the same model using Carierwave in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

To my model, I need to upload two files. One is an image and the other is a pdf file. I upload the image first and then the app take me to a different page to set the title, description, etc. In that page I need to upload the second file. But it does not work. Here's how I set the uploaders in the model :

```
mount_uploader :filename, SubmitUploader
mount_uploader :modelrelease, ModelreleaseUploader
```

The first file is uploading. The second is not. Also note that in the edit screen I edit multiple records at a time. Here's the controller :

```
def uploadscheck
    @submits = Submit.update(params[:submits].keys, params[:submits].values)

    if @submits.empty?
        redirect_to root_url
    else
        @rejected = current_user.rejected
        render 'uploaded'
    end
end
```

I don't get any errors. It simply won't upload. The filed which should have the pdf file have an empty string.

Comment: How do your uploaders look? Your uploader could block certain filetypes.

Comment: hey @EApubs, what about giving me that bounty before the grace period ends? ;-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be a [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#strong-parameters) problem, where you are trying to access the value directly and it doesn't give you the value.

As it is an array or hash, treat it as a scalar value, as shown [here](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values). See if you have file information on

```
params.permit(submits: [])
```

or

```
params.require(:submits).permit!
```